# Want Regular Expression to find match in list elements and then remove unmatched substring from the matching strings

Tags: python, regex

There are two python lists:

```
list1 = ['/data/model/Analyses/.*:Get', '/data/major/.*/project:Get', '/new/data/.*:Put']
list2 = ['data/model/Analyses/Uk5Ynsk:Get', '/data/major/cbd-05-edf-$/project:Get', '/new/data/${he:llo}/variable:Put', '/data/major/sdf?sj85/project:Get']
```

From list1, I want to find the match in `list2` for each element in `list1`. Then want to remove the substring from list2 which is at the place of ".*" in list1.

For example : element from list1 `'/data/major/.*/project:Get'` is matched with elements from list2 `'/data/major/cbd-05-edf-$/project:Get'` and `'/data/major/sdf?sj85/project:Get'`

if matched then, substring in the place of  ".*" should be removed from the list2

```
list1 = ['/data/model/Analyses/.*:Get', '/data/major/.*/project:Get', '/new/data/.*:Put']
list2 = ['data/model/Analyses/Uk5Ynsk:Get', '/data/major/cbd-05-edf-$/project:Get', '/new/data/${he:llo}:Put', '/data/major/sdf?sj85/project:Get']

    Input1 : '/data/major/.*/project:Get'

    Output2 : '/data/major//project:Get' , '/data/major//project:Get'

    Input2 : '/data/model/Analyses/.*:Get'

    Output2 : 'data/model/Analyses/:Get'
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could surround the desired regex pattern in a group match (`(.*)`), and if a match is found replace the content of that group by an empty string.

```py
import re

list1 = ['/data/model/Analyses/.*:Get', '/data/major/.*/project:Get', '/new/data/.*:Put']
list2 = ['/data/model/Analyses/Uk5Ynsk:Get', '/data/major/cbd-05-edf-$/project:Get',
             '/new/data/${he:llo}:Put', '/data/major/sdf?sj85/project:Get']

new_list = []
for l1 in list1:
    for l2 in list2:
        l1_grp = l1.replace('.*','(.*)')
        match = re.search(l1_grp, l2)
        if match:
            new_path = l2.replace(match.group(1),'')
            new_list.append(new_path)

print(new_list)
```

Output from *new_list*

```py
[
    '/data/model/Analyses/:Get',
    '/data/major//project:Get',
    '/data/major//project:Get',
    '/new/data/:Put'
]
```